# Is it possible to read the device's video library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, media-player

As I am making an app which people can use to watch videos, I'd like them to be able to choose videos from their video library. Is it possible to access the library from an app, and if so, where are the videos stored? My app must be able to be used with non-jailbroken devices. SDK is 4.3 at the moment.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the [MediaPlayer framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html).